# What is like irony but used not to deride but to be polite?

Tags: semantics, pragmatics

When I say the opposite of what I mean (or at least minimize the truth) that can be used as what we call irony and is used for derision.  But the (apparently) same strategies are used for politeness.  F.ex. in Persian and Ottoman Turkish an Arabic word meaning '(It's) good' has come to simply mean No.  So obviously this originated with people avoiding saying No and so politely appearing to agree while in reality meaning the opposite. Is there a term for this?

Comment: I don’t think your proposed origin is true; it would be quite unusual for people to (essentially) say yes when they actually mean no and this then being reflected in the meaning of the word changing from ‘yes’ to ‘no’. It seems more likely that it developed the same way as English ‘I’m good’ or ‘That’s all right/okay’ (both meaning ‘no thanks’) – that is, you’re politely avoiding a blunt no by giving the _reason_ you’re saying no instead and leaving the no implicit: ‘no thanks, [it’s/I’m] good the way things are’. I’m sure there’s a name for this, but I’ll be damned if it’ll come to me…

Comment: The same apparent phenomenon happens in Japanese, where いいです "(It) is good" is used to reject an offer. The implicit meaning is something like そのままでいいです "It's fine as it is". I agree with @JanusBahsJacquet that this is not irony either, but is rather attributable to something implicit in the utterance.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much.  I did not know this fact.  My Japanese is crap.  I would appreciate further guidance.  And the point is of course that it is NOT irony as we understand that term.  There is a vast literature on THAT.  The question is whether anyone knows of a TERM for this phenomenon.  I have not found one in the literature I have read so far.  And I need one urgently for something that will be published very soon.  For now I  have introduced the term white irony (playing off of white lie) but if someone has a better one, tell me.

Comment: Also since I need to mention this Japanese example, may I thank you in print?  And if so how?  As "jogloran on StackExchange"?